# ssh rsa authorization login failure on ubuntu desktop

Tags: ssh

server centos7 
client ubuntu 18lts

I got below debug logs while i am trying to remote access the server by using rsa auth:

```
tony@ubuntu18:~$ ssh -v tony@10.0.2.6 -i .ssh/id_rsa


OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.2.6 [10.0.2.6] port 22. 
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 0 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory 
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4 
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.2.6:22 as 'tony' 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:RF83jXuKjMu0X6yUhqsFmgm7lIzpBc/1OwSfBnbSnrs 
debug1: Host '10.0.2.6' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. 
debug1: Found key in /home/tony/.ssh/known_hosts:1 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received 
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512> 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic 
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex 
debug1: No valid Key exchange context 
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic 
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:41zM34vDTpUwzUiS6B6saal7Skkukj839jE2xTlRZk8 .ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 tony@10.0.2.6: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

[authorized_keys on centos7 server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucuFn.png)

[key on ubuntu desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbaOS.png)

[sshd log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQk33.png)

[key_compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G13aM.png)

Comment: Could you add line breaks so that this wall of text becomes readable?

Comment: thanks for cmmts ,i 've updated the text in a more readable format

Comment: check the ```authorized_keys``` file that your ssh key really has access, and check the ssh server logs!

Comment: Key may be incorrect, or directory/file permissions of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server may be too open.

Comment: @Martin  append the sshd server log

Comment: @berndbausch   the privilege for the .ssh dir is set to 700  and 600 for the file authorized_keys

Comment: in your ssh server log, there is no line about an incoming client connection, did you copy the correct timeframe? per default, sshd logs a line for each connection attempt... also, did you check, that your public key is written inside the authorized_keys file ?

Comment: @Martin i've attached the pics of authorized_keys of both vms and the sshd log. thanks for the help

Comment: @Martin i found a link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102502/meaning-of-connection-closed-by-xxx-preauth-in-sshd-logs , is it possible caused by using the wrong command to generate the key ? i used key-gen without any para

Comment: Please add the relevant log entries from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason... the authorized_keys file must be owned by the user, but in your case, it is owned by root ... since sshd is started inside the user context, the sshd cannnot read the authorized_keys file! try a `sudo chown allen:allen .ssh/authorized_keys` on the server...

And if you are unsure if you pasted the wrong public key - the following command "re-generates" the public key for your private key file. Execute:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f <private key file>
```

And compare that line to your authorized_keys file. Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274560/how-do-you-test-a-public-private-dsa-keypair

Comment: hi martin really appreciate your great help and cost of your time . i did change the ownership of  file "authorized_keys" to allen and group to allen .the pic just has not updated in time.   i've attached a pic of key_compare. i  guess they are match

Comment: sorry, then I am out of ideas. Check the sshd_config for anything fancy, and maybe try a chmod 644 authorized_keys ...

Answer (score 0):

hi @martin @berndbausch:

The problem was caused by offering the incorrect pub-key .i had del a chara of the pub-key  without caution during the copy-paste operation.

I will be more careful in the future adventures on linux. Through the trouble-shooting process i have learnt a lot new commands.

thanks to your guys again!

[login succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZH2t.png)
[login log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT93T.png)